# Ninject binding at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am looking at a certain scenario in an application that i am currently working on

I want an Admin officer to be able to change system wide settings in an application.

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
 //bla bla bla

 }
```

At startUp, I have the following binding

```
public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<ApplicationSettings>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
}
```

All is well and Good as I understand that the same instance of the application settings will be served for as long as the kernel is active

My question is this. What if I have to change the applicationsettings at runtime. And I want to automaticcally change the value of the ApplicationSettings instance in the kernel

Will it be possible to do something like this

```
public void ChangeSettings(IKernel kernel, ApplicationSettings setting)
{
   var setting = kernel.Get<ApplicationSettings>();
   //change the values of the instance
}
```

Question, How do i update the kernel binding so that subsequent references to the singleton instance will refer to the newly modified version

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about Rebind<> ?

```
public void ChangeSettings(IKernel kernel, ApplicationSettings setting)
{
   var setting = kernel.Get<ApplicationSettings>();
   kernel.Rebind<ApplicationSettings>().ToConstant(setting);
}
```